# ロールの定義を関数からクラスに変えると、「make html」実行時に「TypeError: … takes no arguments」というエラーが発生する

Tags: python3, sphinx

自己回答で詳細を説明していますが、このエラーが `__init__` に対するものだと気付けば、エラー情報から特定できるソースの該当箇所を見ることで`add_node`の正しい書き方が分かります。

#### 環境

- windows10/cygwin64
- python3.8
- sphinx4.3.0+（開発版）

#### エラー内容

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docutils/parsers/rst/states.py", line 886, in interpreted
    nodes, messages2 = role_fn(role, rawsource, text, lineno, self)
TypeError: ExRole() takes no arguments
```

#### エラーの出るロールの内容

```py
856
857 class ExRole(docutils.SphinxRole):
858     """「:kana:`かな|単語`」によるルビ表示"""
859
860     def run(self):
861         node = KanaText(self.text)
862         return [node], []
863
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 原因

setup内でのadd_roleの記述ミス

正しいコード

```py
929
930     #「:kana:`かな|単語^11`」が使用可能になる
931     app.add_role('kana', ExRole())
932
```

間違っているコード（ExRoleに注目）

```py
929
930     #「:kana:`かな|単語^11`」が使用可能になる
931     app.add_role('kana', ExRole)
932
```

#### 状況と考察

状況

- 参考にしたsphinx拡張は関数型ロールを使っていて、そのまま関数型で使う分には問題なかった。
  これをクラスにしようと変更したら「TypeError」エラーが発生。

考察

- 関数型からクラス型に変えるのに、同じadd_roleを使って登録することに引っかかるものはあったが、「いい感じにしてくれるはず」と根拠のない解釈をしていた。
- エラーから該当のソースを見て `__call__` は目にしていたが、関数型との引数の違いに注目していて `__call__` が使われている意図を見逃していた。

#### 参考

SphinxRoleクラス

```py
346
347 class SphinxRole:
…
364
365     def __call__(self, name: str, rawtext: str, text: str, lineno: int,
366                  inliner: Inliner, options: Dict = {}, content: List[str] = []
367                  ) -> Tuple[List[Node], List[system_message]]:
…
385         return self.run()
386
…
```

add_roleの引数にインスタンス化する前のクラスを渡すと `__init__` が呼び出されれてエラーになる。
インスタンス化した後のオブジェクトが、元の関数型と同等になる。